# Android - display .swf animation (as-is or converted to..?)

Tags: android, animation, flash

I'm developing an application in which 2D animations will be displayed over a live-camera preview. The animations have 20-30 objects over a transparent background and the camera preview must be visible during the animation. Note that I am receiving finished SWF animations and have to either recreate them in code or figure out a way to display them as-is.

I have researched the options below. *Can anyone give any suggestions for how to approach showing or easily recreating the SWF animations in Android?*

- OpenGL - tried this and got partway (basic animation running with camera still visible), but it's quite a lot of work to recreate the complex movement and timing in the SWFs. Just recreating one SWF took a day or two of work and I have many animations to recreate.
- Android 2D animation - the built-in animation classes will make it a bit easier to do movement/timing, but I still have to recreate the original animation
- WebView (??) - is it possible to display a background transparent swf in a transparent webview over a surface view? Has anyone had any luck with transparent SWFs in android? Transparent webviews seem to work according to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2)
- Convert the SWF to a movie and play it...with a transparent background? I can't imagine this would work and have found nothing online to suggest it's possible but...

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is tasked with rendering/recreating Flash animations in an Android app - seems there is no alternative but to rewrite the animation in OpenGL.

Comment: Have you written any blog on how one can get started with conversion from flash animations to openGL? That would help a lot.