# Transparent Background + Flash in WebView on Android 3.0+?

Tags: android, flash, background, webview, transparent

I want a WebView with a transparent background and a flash content.
These two things work perfectly separatly but not together. So for flash i need `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` but then the background won't be transparent. If i set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` the background will become pretty transparent but I won't see any flash content.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: How are you setting the background transparent?

Comment: It works with `webView.setBackgroundColor(0);` and a transparent background by html..

Comment: is that what you are doing, or does that fix the problem? If that fixes the problem then write it up as a solution and accept it so people in the future can use it

Comment: No that doesn't solve my problem: `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` --> Flash works, but a white background; `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` --> Flash doesn't work, but a transparent background

Answer (score 0):

Check out this similar question on stack overflow:
[Android WebView style background-color:transparent ignored on android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2)  it appears to be a bug that has been reported

Comment: Thanks.. That's very bad! Is there another way to get a flash content in my app?