# "body background-color: transparent" did not affect on webview of android 4.0.3

Tags: android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want to display webView on static image on imageView.

I set transparent color to webView like this

```
webview.setBackground(0);
```

I set background-color as transparent

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color:transparent">
</body>
</html>
```

but Webview's background keep displaying as white.

I show any questions and try these following page's solution but nothing to change.

- [Android WebView style background-color:transparent ignored on android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2)
- [Transparent Background + Flash in WebView on Android 3.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796346/transparent-background-flash-in-webview-on-android-3-0)

Do you have any ideas? Please help me.

Comment: This issue is fixed in Android 4.1.1.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem with the white WebView background on a device with ICS (4.0)!

The answer from NcJlee did remove the white background from the webview, but it requires API level 11! It will not work on older API's!

```
    webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

The solution is to set a android:layerType="software" attribute on the webview in the .xml layout resource.

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviev"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layerType="software" />
```

Comment: On ICS, I just had to disable "Force GPU Rendering" in the system settings like NcJiee mentioned, and then setBackgroundColor to Color.TRANSPARENT. However, I had to remove setLayerType statement, which is not available on API level 10.

Answer (score 5):

One way to avoid this is to uncheck "Force GPU Rendering" in

```
    Settings -> Developer Options -> Force GPU Rendering
```

But that doesn't solve the problem. I've tried this code in emulator and it works. By forcing the webview to render by using software instead of hardware acceleration.

```
    webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this code to transprent webview

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

attempts to invoke setLayerType or specify android:layerType in xml caused compilation errors for me. This happened despite setting minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion to 11+.

So, I ended up using reflection to call setLayerType as recommended in: [Transparent WebView not working on Android v4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282333/transparent-webview-not-working-on-android-v4-0)