# Android WebView and html transparent background

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

I'm developing an Android app and i found some issues in setting background color as transparent.
I have one activity that contains one WebView. I load a page in this activity that contains a picture.

I want to visualize the png picture (with transparent background) in my app with no backgrounds.

So I did the following:

in my jsp:

```
...

<div style="background-color: transparent">
   <img src="linuxPicture.png">
</div>
```

in my Android class:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
webView.load("http://www.myWebPage.com");
```

But I think something wrong because i continue see the white background of the WebView. You can see [this](https://ibb.co/JnMX3Qg) image (I think the problem is linked to html but I have no idea how resolve it)

Do you? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Replace 
`webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

with
`WebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(1, 255, 255, 255));`

See: [Transparent WebView not working on Android v4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282333/transparent-webview-not-working-on-android-v4-0/17815574#17815574)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wrong syntax. Try this

```
<div style="background-color: transparent"> <img src="linuxPicture.png"> </div>
```

Comment: edited. I transcribed it wrongly. That's not the solution