# Android WebView flicker bug while animating view on device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-webview, android-animation

I am attempting to implement slide-in navigation (a la Facebook, Path, or Google+ Android apps).  The complete source to reproduce this bug [can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/robertkarl/slide-navigation-web-view).

When animating a `WebView` off the screen however, on a device, flickering occurs, as if the device is taking a bite out of my `WebView` just before pushing it off the screen.

[image: WebView slide nav menu IN (device)]

The artifact does not occur on the emulator! The animation proceeds smoothly.

[image: WebView slide nav menu IN (emulator)]

Interestingly, this flickering seems to only occur when the view being animated is a `WebView`! Here is the same project using a TextView as the main content view.

[image: TextView slide nav menu IN (device)]

Layout for the web view activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And for the text view activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/web_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello there. no flicker!"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code called to slide the navigation menu in:

```
 private void slideIn() {
        LinearLayout actionBarFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        menuView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, null);
        menuView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(SIZE, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.LEFT));
        FrameLayout decorView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.addView(menuView);
        decorView.bringChildToFront(actionBarFrame);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) actionBarFrame.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(SIZE, 0, -SIZE, 0);
        actionBarFrame.setLayoutParams(params);

        TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(-SIZE, 0, 0, 0);
        ta.setDuration(DURATION); 
        actionBarFrame.startAnimation(ta);
    }
```

And to slide it back out:

```
    private void slideOut() {
        LinearLayout actionBarFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent();

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) actionBarFrame.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        actionBarFrame.setLayoutParams(params);

        TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(SIZE, 0, 0, 0);
        ta.setDuration(DURATION);
        ta.setAnimationListener(new  AnimationListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                ((FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(menuView);
                menuView = null;
            }
            @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) { }
            @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) { }
        });
        actionBarFrame.startAnimation(ta);
    }
```

I uploaded the code to [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/robertkarl/slide-navigation-web-view) as a public repo so you can try this project exactly as I have.

Any help or ideas about why this is happening or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated! What is desired is to smoothly animate the `WebView` out of the picture and back in. Thanks!

Comment: same issue here. @Robert did you find solution for this?

Comment: @jayellos there are two potential fixes to this problem. I'll add an answer below, but the moral of the story is that enabling hardware acceleration on the `WebView` can help (it's not on by default on some platforms), or using [this library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) (our current solution).

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, it seems the problem has to do with a bug when using `WebViews` with hardware acceleration enabled on 3.0+ devices. I also tried using the [sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library with a `WebView` but experienced the same flicker problem. After looking around I found a workaround here:

[WebView “flashing” with white background if hardware acceleration is enabled (Android 3.0+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476151/webview-flashing-with-white-background-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled-an)

The workaround uses the following code to set the layer type of the `WebView` to software rendering:

```
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

This code solved the flicker for me with the drawback of lower performance.

Comment: I can confirm that workaround works. Did someone found a solution that permits hardware acceleration?