# WebView blinks when loading an HTML page from assets folder

Tags: android, html, webview

I am loading a very small HTML content, which is stored in my assets folder. But the problem is that it blinks on the screen first and then shows the content. I searched for the problem, but found nothing good. My code is given below along with xml.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_nearby);

        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);  
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/intro.html"); 
    }
```

My XML

```
<WebView 
            android:id="@+id/WebView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"             
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix your issue is to disable hardware acceleration http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

`webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` should disable hardware acceleration for the web view and do the trick.

You can also refer to this thread [WebView "flashing" with white background if hardware acceleration is enabled (Android 3.0+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476151/webview-flashing-with-white-background-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled-an) where people may also different solutions.

Comment: thanks for your answer here. I have tried both of them, but nothing happens

Comment: what did `webview.isHardwareAccelerated()` return ? Have you tried to add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` at application or actvity tag in manifest ?