# Android WebView background color

Tags: android, webview, background-color

I am adding to my layout a WebView to display justified text. I want to set the background of the WebView to be transparent to appear like a textView. Here's what I did:

```
WebView synopsis;
synopsis=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.synopsis);
synopsis.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

It works on the emulator, but when I run the application on my device it doesn't work: what I get is a white background.

```
 String textTitleStyling = "<head><style>* {margin:0;padding:0;font-size:20; text-align:justify; color:#FFFFFF;}</style></head>";
 String titleWithStyle = textTitleStyling + "<body><h1>" + movie.synopsis + "</h1></body>";
 synopsis.loadData(textTitleStyling + movie.synopsis, "text/html", "utf-8");
 synopsis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.synopsis);
 synopsis.getSettings();
 synopsis.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Try setting the background like this:

```
WebView synopsis;
synopsis=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.synopsis);
synopsis.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: this method is working **only** if you specify color directly like:

`synopsis.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);`



tested on Samsung Tab 4 7" android 4.4.2

Comment: what's the point of using "getSettings()"? you are not using it.

Comment: I agree, "geSettings()" is not necessary. The solution worked quite nice though :)

Answer (score 33):

try below code hope use full for you:-

```
webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#919191"));
```

grey code : `#919191`

Answer (score 21):

You must put this in the XML code :

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

for your web view like this for example :

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/MyWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

and after this you must go to Java code and write this before loadUrl :

```
yourWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: I didn't need to put android:background="@android:color/transparent" in my XML, it was enough to just do setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); in the code. (Only changing the XML did not work for me)

Comment: If using Xamarin, `webview.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is the only way I could get it to work and not load an initial white background first, if I had dark mode on:

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
   />
```

Answer (score 2):

What I do is

```
 synopsis.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe you should write the full code (including html) because I'm afraid the mistake is there.

Comment: This is the code
{ String textTitleStyling = "<head><style>* {margin:0;padding:0;font-size:20; text-align:justify; color:#FFFFFF;}</style></head>";
     String titleWithStyle = textTitleStyling + "<body><h1>" + movie.synopsis + "</h1></body>";
     synopsis.loadData(textTitleStyling + movie.synopsis, "text/html", "utf-8");
     synopsis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.synopsis);
     synopsis.getSettings();
     synopsis.setBackgroundColor(0);}

Answer (score 2):

Did you load the css in ur webview?

Something like:

```
synopsis.loadData(textTileStyling, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

or

```
synopsis.loadDataWithBaseURL("", textTileStyling, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: or synopsis.loadDataWithBaseURL("", textTileStyling, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my post, you will find how i did load data

Answer (score 1):

You can find a few tips here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14749 and also here:
[Android WebView style background-color:transparent ignored on android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2)

Answer (score 1):

Your html code sets everything to white

**Replace:**

```
    String textTitleStyling = "<head><style>* {margin:0;padding:0;font-size:20; " + 
    "text-align:justify; color:#FFFFFF;}</style></head>"; 

    String titleWithStyle = textTitleStyling + "<body><h1>" + movie.synopsis +
    "</h1></body>";

    synopsis.loadData(textTitleStyling + movie.synopsis, "text/html", "utf-8"); 
    synopsis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.synopsis); 
    synopsis.getSettings(); 
    synopsis.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

**With:**

This excludes color from header style and applies the rest of the style only to body element

```
    String textTitleStyling = "<head><style>body{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:20; " + 
    "text-align:justify;}</style></head>"; 

    String titleWithStyle = textTitleStyling + "<body><h1>" + movie.synopsis +
    "</h1></body>";

    synopsis.loadData(titleWithStyle, "text/html", "utf-8"); 
    synopsis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.synopsis); 
    synopsis.getSettings(); 
    synopsis.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

EDIT: fixed html

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it -

```
webview.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Here `android.R.color.transparent` is **transparent color** which is belongs to android fragmework.