# transparency webView

Tags: java, android, transparency

I am trying to make my background webView transparent like that :

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

but it doesn't work and if I add this line everything is transparent(I don't see my html page) :

```
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

I read that some times there is a problem when this android:hardwareAccelerated="true"  is in the manifest, but I don't have this line.

HTML :

```
<BODY style=\"padding:0;margin:0;\">
<div style="padding:0;margin:0;background:transparent;border:none;position:relative;cursor:pointer;overflow:hidden;height:165px;">
<object ggnoclick ggswfcid name="fo_GGUID" id="fo_GGUID" width="100%" height="165" data="http://c.gumgum.com/ads/com/cesar/big_dogs/cesar_250x100_01.swf?modalURL=GGUID" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" background="transparent" style="background:transparent;">
    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
</div>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

This works for my case.I use android 2.2.
See that same topic in [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2)