# Showing WebView as AlertDialog content

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create a `AlertDialog` that has rich content.
When I use the `Html.fromHtml()` to set the message text like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
adb.setTitle("title");
adb.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

it only allows me basic HTML elements like `&lt;b&gt;`(Bold) and `&lt;i&gt;`(Italic).

When I use a `WebView` like

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
myWebView.loadData(webContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
adb.setView(webView);
```

I lose the default Android style.

What can I do to get Rich context, like `&lt;ul&gt;` inside an `AlertDialog`?.

Comment: what do you mean by you loose default android style?

Comment: I use `Theme.Holo` (which's black), but when I use a WebView, it doesn't use the style.

Comment: Look at my comment for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the webview inside an activity , and set the activity theme as dialog in menifest file :

```
<activity .....
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Use custom Adapter

```
final Dialog custon_dialog = new Dialog(Login.this);
custon_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
custon_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.webview);
custon_dialog.setCancelable(true);
// custon_dialog.setTitle(null);

WebView mwebview = (WebView) custon_dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mwebview.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    mwebview.loadData(webContent, "text/html", "utf-8");
custon_dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Has the same problem, I lose the style setting

Comment: mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2

Comment: This is only about the background, Theme.Holo has more settings I want to have inside the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

> Html.fromHtml(text) uses tagsoup

does support simple tags for your reference [html.fromhtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler%29)

Inspite of using

```
String text="some html code";
```

**create an html file with your css etc. and place all the files in the assets folder of your application.**

Now , in place of this

```
adb.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

> as you want **Rich content** displayed in the **alerdialog**.

**This should help you , Remember: you can also inflate the Dialog with a custom layout of your own**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(yourclass.this);

   alert.setTitle("title");
   WebView wv = new WebView(yourclass.this);

   wv.loadUrl("file:///assets/yourHtmlFileName.html");

                        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
                        {
                            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                            {
                                view.loadUrl(url);

                                return true;
                            }
                        });

                        alert.setView(wv);

                        alert.show();

                    }
                });
```

Comment: So I'm bound to the CSS? and can't use Holo.Theme?.

Comment: Remember: you can also inflate the Dialog with a custom layout of your own . With this line I want to state that in your layout.xml you can use `@android:style/Theme.Holo` as `android:background` in layout.xml's root element.