# Kindle Fire, HTML page with video, and WebView background color issue

Tags: android, webview, kindle

We have problem with embedded video playing in WebView's on Kindle Fire HD 7" with latest firmware (Android 4.0.3, firmware rev 7.4.6).

Prerequisites:

- static magazine page image (from JPG file) displayed on screen (ImageView used);
- HTML page displayed over static image (WebView inside custom layout; both WebView and 
  layout backgrounds are transparent!);
- HTML page contains 'video' tag inside 'iframe' tag.

On all tested devices this combination works fine: WebView draws with transparent background over static page image, so, video on HTML page properly placed inside static JPEG from ImageView. Except Kindle Fire.

On Kindle Fire, WebView always draws with white non-transparent background. WebView doesn't react to setBackgroundColor or setBackgroundDrawable calls. Attempt to set HTML body background color from Javascript also unsuccessful. So, static image is not visible under HTML 'overlay'.

Suggested by this topic - [Android WebView style background-color:transparent ignored on android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003156/android-webview-style-background-colortransparent-ignored-on-android-2-2) - I'm trying to switch off hardware acceleration for WebView:

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Kindle Fire draws WebView with proper, transparent background. But video on web page fails after that! More precisely, when starting video, only audio play, no picture.

Summary: hardware acceleration on - WebView draws with improper background; hw acceleration off - video in HTML plays without picture.

Few days googling doesn't result in any solution. Somebody solved a similar problem on the Kindle Fire or other device?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using the <video> tag to play it?

Comment: Yes, <video> tag used to play video clip. Flash player can't be used on Kindle devices.