# WebViewClient - transparent background for later OS versions

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm targeting SDK version 27 and currently testing on Oreo (physical device) and API19 (emulator) and want to set the background of a WebView to transparent.

There are a lot of answers for earlier API/SDK versions, but nothing seems to be working for me on these versions.

Specifically I am loading a URL that returns an image only into my WebView. The WebView is slightly wider than the image (as the image size may vary).

I can always see a black background around the image (I have confirmed that this is NOT part of the image)

In the `onPageFinished` method of the `WebViewClient` attached to my WebView I am trying all of the following:

```
wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
wv.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
wv.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
```

I have also set the layer type to `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the above code WAS in fact making the `WebView` transparent and that the black surround that I was seeing was actually the default background of the pseudo-`body` of the rendered page when the page contains only an image. ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24475695/2211491) gave me the clue!)

The trick, therefore was to create an HTML page on the fly with a transparent `body` and include the image in that page rather than just loading the image into the `WebView` directly.

So, using:

```
wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
wv.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

in the `onPageFinished` method AND using

```
String myHTML = "<html><body style=\"background: transparent; margin:0; padding:0;\"><img src=\"" +
                myImgURL + "\"></body></html>";
wv.loadData(myHTML, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Has achieved the desired effect of displaying the image in the WebView as though it were directly on the canvas.

(Note that I have tried with and without the `setLayerType` line and it still works in Oreo - it may or may not be needed in other versions)

Answer (score 0):

This will make the `webview` activity transparent.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Add this as the theme of the webview activity in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
```

Comment: The WebView is just one widget on an activity with a whole bunch of other stuff so an activity level theme doesn't seem appropriate - or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: then try using it as the theme of the `webview`. But I never tried it.

Comment: dont you mean <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent">